# Aging when travelling at relativistic speeds

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, inertial-frames, observers

I have a twin. If I acquired a craft that travels at 10% of light speed and wanted to go to Proxima Centauri, it seems now like it would take me 42 years to get there. Would I be 42 years older when I arrive though and would my twin, still on Earth, be 42 years older when I arrive?

Comment: By the way, to make the calculations easier, use v=(3/5)c or v=(4/5)c... and you'll end up with relatively-simple fractions (the square-roots will simplify). [These good v's have rational doppler factors $\sqrt{(1+v)/(1-v)}$.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume you travel at constant speed, and that in your earthbound twin's rest frame, the distance between Earth and Proxima Centauri were 4.2 light years.

To your twin, it would seem that your journey took 42 years, and he would say that he is 42 years older when you arrive than when you took off.

To you, the distance between Earth and Proxima Centauri is Lorentz contracted. In your frame of reference, the distance between the planet and the star is thus reduced to

$$ \frac{42 \text{ ly}}{ \gamma} = 41.7 \text{ ly},$$

where $\gamma = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{v}{c}\right)^2}} \approx 1.005$ when you travel at a speed of $v =0.1$c.

Hence, you would say that you were 41.7 years older when you arrived compared to when you took off from Earth. Additionally, the odometer on your spacecraft would say that you had only traveled 4.17 light years, and not the 4.2 light years that you might have expected without taking special relativity into account.

Comment: But also note: Comparing your age with the age of somebody who is separated from you by a distance of 4.2 light years is an entire problem in itself. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_synchronisation